# Android Studio 3/Kotlin code coverage

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, kotlin, code-coverage

My android app is multi module project:

```
include (android-app/kotlin-android)':application', (pure kotlin)':presentation', (pure kotlin)':domain', (android-library/kotin-android)':dataproviders'
```

I'm using Junit/Mockito for tests and I have issue with generating code coverage for kotlin android modules **only**. 
[image: code coverage report]
Tested lines are visible for android studio.

**tested class in ui.viewmodel package:**

[image: tested lines for kotlin-android module]

But, for **pure kotlin** (eg. domain, presentation) test coverage works fine:
[image: code coverage report pure kotlin module]

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 8 
You can look at my build.gradle files at github:

[build.gradle](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie/blob/master/build.gradle)

[dependencies.gradle](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie/blob/master/dependencies.gradle)

[application.build.gradle](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie/blob/master/application/build.gradle)

[presentation.build.gradle](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie/blob/master/presentation/build.gradle)

Example test in android application module:

[MostPopularViewModelTest](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie/blob/master/application/src/test/kotlin/pl/hypeapp/episodie/ui/viewmodel/MostPopularViewModelTest.kt)

Example test in pure kotlin module:

[MostPopularPresenterTest](https://github.com/hypeapps/episodie/blob/master/presentation/src/test/kotlin/pl/hypeapp/presentation/mostpopular/MostPopularPresenterTest.kt)

Can someone help me with my problem? I tried generate code coverage via Jacoco but it also did not show code coverage.

Comment: Similar post: [Android Studio 3.0 gradle 3.0.0-beta2, breaks Kotlin Unit Test Coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45819700/8583692)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution is to add this this gradle task in build.gradle for module:

```
task copyTestClasses(type: Copy) {
    from "build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debugUnitTest"
    into "build/intermediates/classes/debug"
}
```

And run:

```
gradlew copyTestClasses
```

Then generate code coverage report without problems.

Comment: This seems like reporting the test instead of the code coverage?

Comment: Thanks for this tip! @Elye is right, you should copy from "build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug"

Comment: @Hype Take a look at the pending edit, and approve it if you deem it necessary to improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although the solution from @Hype works, it also messes a bit the environment as you end up with kotlin class files and META-INF in the same directory as the class files from java. This might give you some issues running the compilation for a second time.

Another solution would be to just add the path for kotlin classes to jacoco configuration parameter `classDirectories`.
This solution would simply tell jacoco that it needs to evaluate files from two different file trees. The upside is that it does not change your environment.
Here's a sample of how you could combine class files from multiple directories, excluding any unwanted files (this is depending on your project setup, you might use dagger and have to exclude dagger generated files):

```
def javaAndKotlinClassFiles = files(fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/classes/${sourcePath}",
                                excludes: ['**/R.class',
                                           '**/R$*.class',
                                           '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                                           '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                                           '**/BuildConfig.*',
                                           '**/Manifest*.*',
                                           '**/*$Lambda$*.*', // Jacoco can not handle several "$" in class name.
                                           '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
                                           '**/*$*$*.*', // Anonymous classes generated by kotlin
                                           '**/*Test*.*', // Test files
                                           '**/*Spec*.*' // Test files
                                ]
                                    ).files)
                    .from(files(fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/${sourcePath}",
                            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                                       '**/R$*.class',
                                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                                       '**/*$ViewBinder*.*',
                                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                                       '**/Manifest*.*',
                                       '**/*$Lambda$*.*', // Jacoco can not handle several "$" in class name.
                                       '**/*_Provide*Factory*.*',
                                       '**/*$*$*.*', // Anonymous classes generated by kotlin
                                       '**/*Test*.*', // Test files
                                       '**/*Spec*.*' // Test files
                                    ]).files)
                    )
            classDirectories = javaAndKotlinClassFiles
```

Here's a [nice guide](https://github.com/nomisRev/AndroidGradleJacoco) for how to set it up for Java.